# Pandas value error when converting JSON into an excel

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

JSON File:-

```
 {"customer_name":"james",
   "customer_id":41
 }
```

my Python code below gives the error message :-

```
  " ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index "
```

Please let me know what is the issue in the below code.

```
import pandas
pandas.read_json("p1.json").to_excel("out-put.xlsx")
```

Comment: This issue might be cause of incapable type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
pandas.read_json("p1.json", typ = 'series')
```

It creates pd.Series

Comment: TypeError: read_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'type'

Comment: Sorry, it is **typ**